# How to find the http url when run yum install in docker image "centos/python-36-centos7"

Tags: linux, image, docker, yum

The docker is runnning in a private subnet, and I need to open url based whitelist for it to connect Internet. For example, if I add ".fedoraproject.org", then in this docker, we can access https://dl.fedoraproject.org.

But now, when I yum install package, I don't know how to check which http url "centos/python-36-centos7" uses.

This is part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/python-36-centos7

# ...

RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
#needed by git-codecommit
# RUN yum -y install https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo-1.7-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN wget https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo-1.7-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum localinstall -y endpoint-repo-1.7-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum -y install git aws-cli cmake3
```

This command `yum -y install git aws-cli cmake3` timeout:

```
https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received')
https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received')
https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received')
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install git aws-cli cmake3' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for,

The docker registry path for the official images is `library/(image)`, an example is shown below,

`docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/library/busybox`